# How to receive PUSH Notifications properly?

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications, voip, callkit, pushkit

I am writing VoIP application using Xcode 9.2, Swift 4.0, minimum iOS version is 10.3. I want to receive incoming call even iPhone is in sleeping mode (just like WhatsApp or Viber). I already know that I must use CallKit for it. But I do not know how to receive PUSH Notifications correctly. I mean, I have two ways how to receive them. First is in AppDelegate.swift, please, look (this method is working):

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        //Getting permissions for Notifications
        //222
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { granted, error in
        }
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        //222

        return true
    }

    //For PUSH Notifications settings

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("NOTIFICATION ERROR: \(error)")
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        let pushToken = deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)}).lowercased()
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        // Receiving call?
    }

}
```

But, no matter, what I am doing, it does not trigger incoming call if iPhone is sleeping. Lately I saw that there is another method to receive PUSH Notifications. Please, look:

```
import UIKit
import CallKit
import PushKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CXProviderDelegate, PKPushRegistryDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let registry = PKPushRegistry(queue: nil)
        registry.delegate = self
        registry.desiredPushTypes = [PKPushType.voIP]
    }

    func providerDidReset(_ provider: CXProvider) {
    }

    func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXAnswerCallAction) {
        action.fulfill()
    }

    func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXEndCallAction) {
        action.fulfill()
    }

    func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didUpdate pushCredentials: PKPushCredentials, for type: PKPushType) {
        print(pushCredentials.token.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0) }.joined())
    }

    func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        // Receive call?
    }

}
```

The problem is that in first method I have this PUSH token: 9bcf73ac3d6a68be07c26d8b6a972f5b716cd5308f1a19048b62d19b9b8d4bd1

Second method returns me this PUSH token: 
1e40fafb2963161b1bcf1bdde00d625a879c6934e19e2fb32f62b1c9272e956f

And they are not equal! How can this be? So, main question is: how to receive PUSH Notifications and what is difference between AppDelegate and PushKit methods and which token is correct?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of Notifications (in fact more, but, in this case, just two): PUSH Notifications and VoIP Notifications. They have different tokens and different system of receiving. VoIP services exists only for calls (Apple CallKit), opposite PUSH service exists for messages and other notifications. So, in fact, both of this methods are necessary and one does not replaces another. And both of this methods requiring different Certificates in Apple Developer Account: Apple Push Notification service SSL for PUSH Notifications and VoIP Services Certificate for VoIP.
Thank you everyone for help! Be free to edit this if you see a error.

Comment: True, understanding much on VOIP integration you can refer https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/PushKit_SilentPushNotification for creating PEM file, handling VOIP notification, local notification to alert user, receive call in any app state etc.

Comment: Thank you! Your comment is even better! Truly, you can receive VoIP notification and then show user local notification, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove this line application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

Now comes to puskit below method will have right token

```
   func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didUpdate credentials: PKPushCredentials, forType type: PKPushType) {
    print("\(#function) voip token: \(credentials.token)")

    let deviceToken = credentials.token.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1) })
    print("\(#function) token is: \(deviceToken)")}
```

and Push-kit framework does not have UI like remote or local notification you need to trigger local notification every time when below method called

```
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    // Receive call?
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer, but I want you to read mine when it will appear there. I want somebody smart checks my conclusions. Thank you one more time!